# how to load data to jupyter notebook VM from google cloud?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to load a bunch of csv files stored on my google cloud into my jupyter notebook. I use python 3 and `gsutil` does not work.

Lets's assume I have 6 .csv files in '\bucket1\1'.  does anybody know what I should do?

Comment: Have you installed Jupyter on a normal VM, are you using one of the deep-learning VMs that come with Jupyter installed or are you using Google Cloud Datalab (Google's superset of Jupyter)?

Comment: After defining my instance, I clicked on its SSH and typed in the following code in the console:  ``jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888 --no-browser &`` this produced a key which I used when I wanted to log in on the jupyter on my browser

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are running a [Jupyter Notebook](https://jupyter.org/) on a Google Cloud VM instance. And you want to load 6 .csv files (that you currently have on your Cloud Storage) into it.

Install the dependencies:

```
pip install google-cloud-storage
pip install pandas
```

Run the following script on your Notebook:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd

bucket_name = "my-bucket-name"

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)

# When you have your files in a subfolder of the bucket.
my_prefix = "csv/" # the name of the subfolder
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix = my_prefix, delimiter = '/')

for blob in blobs:
    if(blob.name != my_prefix): # ignoring the subfolder itself 
        file_name = blob.name.replace(my_prefix, "")
        blob.download_to_filename(file_name) # download the file to the machine
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name) # load the data
        print(df)

# When you have your files on the first level of your bucket

blobs = bucket.list_blobs()

for blob in blobs:
    file_name = blob.name
    blob.download_to_filename(file_name) # download the file to the machine
    df = pd.read_csv(file_name) # load the data
    print(df)
```

Notes:

- [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html) is a good dependency used when dealing with data analysis in python, so it will make it easier for you to work with the csv files.
- The code contains 2 alternatives: one if you have the objects inside a subfolder and other one if you have the objects on the first level, use the one that applies to your case.
- The code cycles through all the objects, so you might get errors if you have some other kind of objects in there.
- In case you already have the files on the machine where you are running the Notebook, then you can ignore the Google Cloud Storage lines and just specify the root/relative path of each file on the "read_csv" method.
- For more information about listing Cloud Storage objects go [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects) and for downloading Cloud Storage objects go [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects).

Comment: Thanks for the code. Let me explain the situation a little better. I am using jupyter notebook, which runs on google cloud. In other words, I am using google cloud computing. I also have my data files (the six csv files) both on my local machine and on google cloud. What I want to do is that I want to have access to these data files to process them using my jupyter notebook on google cloud. One way is to "update" the files, but they are too big! I am looking for a more pythonic way to have access to these files.

Comment: Let me see if I understood correctly: You are running a Jupyter on a Google Cloud VM instance. You have the files on your local machine and also on Google Cloud Storage. You want to be able to load the files on your Notebook that is running on the VM. I have edited my answer to incorporate a more pythonic way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of downloading files from your bucket directly to your Jupyter Notebook works like this:

```
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('gs://name-of-your-bucket/path-to-your-file/name-of-your-file.csv', sep=",")
```

So here you also make use of the pandas library and directly specifying the path to your file in your Google Cloud Storage it via "gs://...".